# python generator function not yielding output

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

```
import itertools
def password_generator():
    with open("D:\Password Hacker\Password Hacker\\task\passwords.txt", "r") as passfile:
        for word in passfile:
            if not word.isdigit():
                for var in itertools.product(*([letter.lower(), letter.upper()]for letter in word.strip("\n"))):
                    yield ("".join(var))
            else:
                yield (word.strip("\n"))

g = password_generator()
for i in range(10):
print(g.__next__()) #prints same result everytime...
```

The code generates all possible combinations of uppercase and lowercase letters in a word from the file passwords.txt. However, the code outputs same result in each iteration

Comment: Can you please share an example of "passwords.txt", as well as output and expected output. Also your print statement should be indented.

Comment: @Linden each line in the file has different words that are possible passwords, we just need to try all possible combinations of uppercase and lower case letters in each word, ex the first three words in "password.txt" are "123456", "qwerty" and "password". The output for "123456" should be the same as "123456" but for "qwerty" it should print all combinations like "Qwerty", "qWerty" etc. But the only output I am getting is "123456" in every iteration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try :

```
import itertools


def password_generator():
    with open("D:\Password Hacker\Password Hacker\\task\passwords.txt", "r") as passfile:
        for word in passfile:

            print('word : ', word , type(word), word.isdigit()) #you can comment out this line

            if not word.strip("\n").isdigit():
                for var in itertools.product(*([letter.lower(), letter.upper()]for letter in word.strip("\n"))):
                    yield ("".join(var))
            else:
                yield (word.strip("\n"))

g = password_generator()

  
try :  
    while g:
        print(g.__next__()) #prints same result everytime...
        
except:
    print('empty')
```

input `passwords.txt` file:

```
pippo
pluto
123456
```

output:

```
word :  pippo
 <class 'str'> False
pippo
pippO
pipPo
pipPO
piPpo
piPpO
piPPo
piPPO
pIppo
pIppO
pIpPo
pIpPO
pIPpo
pIPpO
pIPPo
pIPPO
Pippo
PippO
PipPo
PipPO
PiPpo
PiPpO
PiPPo
PiPPO
PIppo
PIppO
PIpPo
PIpPO
PIPpo
PIPpO
PIPPo
PIPPO
word :  pluto
 <class 'str'> False
pluto
plutO
pluTo
pluTO
plUto
plUtO
plUTo
plUTO
pLuto
pLutO
pLuTo
pLuTO
pLUto
pLUtO
pLUTo
pLUTO
Pluto
PlutO
PluTo
PluTO
PlUto
PlUtO
PlUTo
PlUTO
PLuto
PLutO
PLuTo
PLuTO
PLUto
PLUtO
PLUTo
PLUTO
word :  123456
 <class 'str'> False
123456
empty
```

you can get same result using:

```
import itertools


def count_pwd():
    with open("passwords.txt", "r") as passfile:
        
        cnt = 0
        
        for word in passfile.readlines():
            
            if not word.strip("\n").isdigit():
            
                cnt += 2**len(word)
                
            else:
                
                cnt += 1


    return cnt        
        
    

def password_generator():
    with open("D:\Password Hacker\Password Hacker\\task\passwords.txt", "r") as passfile:
        
        for word in passfile.readlines():
            
                
                if not word.strip("\n").isdigit():
                    for var in itertools.product(*([letter.lower(), letter.upper()]for letter in word.strip("\n"))):
                        yield ("".join(var))
                else:
                    yield (word.strip("\n"))


g = password_generator()


gg = count_pwd()

print(gg)

try: 
    for i in range(gg):
        print(g.__next__()) #prints same result everytime...
        
except:
    print('empty')
```

anyway you get unwanted duplicated is your `password.txt` file

contains pwds like `22B` or `1a3`